# Correct size/position of nested brackets within fractions

Tags: math-mode, brackets, size

How can I get the correct size/position of the brackets in all 4 "sections", not only in #2?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

TEXT-1-A
$a = \left[ \frac{b}%
                   {c + \left[ \frac de \right]}
       \right]
$
TEXT-1-B

TEXT-2-A
\[ a = \left[ \frac{b}%
                   {c + \left[ \frac de \right]}
       \right]
\]
TEXT-2-B

TEXT-3-A \footnote{TEXT-3-C
$ a = \left[ \frac{b}%
                   {c + \left[ \frac de \right]}
       \right]
$ TEXT-3-D}
TEXT-3-B

TEXT-4-A \footnote{TEXT-4-C
\[ a = \left[ \frac{b}%
                   {c + \left[ \frac de \right]}
       \right]
\] TEXT-4-D}
TEXT-4-B

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you precise what you mean by "correct size/positioning"? What should the output look like?

Comment: I would never write such a construction within `$...$` only displayed.

Comment: Between TEXT.1.A and TEXT.1.B (and the same in .3 and .4) the outer brackets are much higher than the whole fraction, whereas in .2 they have just the "correct" height to enclose the whole fraction and nothing more. (If I could show how it should look like I already would have solved the problem.)

Comment: In other words: the formula should four times look like in example 2.